# Google is against display:none; how about the jquery $(".class").remove()?

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a tumblr theme and I dont want to display posts with a particular class. The only way to do this is through `.class { display:none; }` or the jQuery `$(".class").remove();`

I know that Google would not like it as there is a large amount of content to be hidden from the user but visible to the search engines.

I want to make sure: if I use `$(".class").remove();` it is the same as `display: none;` for Google, or would Google be ok with that?

Comment: Google doesn't execute javascript when they're spidering your page. If you want to hide stuff from google, then put a `rel="noindex"` on the appropriate containers.

Comment: @Marc B I believe the OP is _not_ trying to hide it from Google. I think they're trying to still get crawled by Google but not have them "mark down" the site as having data that's initially hidden from the user (as spam sites will do).

Comment: Display none does not hurt SEO. [It's been asked here a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=seo+display+none&submit=search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript/jquery is no use, Google won't render it when it crawls anyway.

Best stick to `display: none;`, I don't think you'd get a huge black mark. At worst, google won't crawl your hidden content, add `rel="noindex"` to each post to be sure

Comment: That's ok then, as the content that I am hiding in that page appears in another

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.class').hide()` instead.  jQuery [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) actually removes the element.  But jQuery [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) leave the element in place and hides it with applied CSS

---

Answer (score 1):

I think -

```
$(".class").hide();
```

is the same as `display:none;`. `remove()` will remove elements from the DOM.

Comment: that's why I thought I;d use remove() the thing is I have no choice in what is written by tumblr, the only way to remove the content I dont want is through display:none or remove()

Comment: `hide()` should hide the content in the same way `display:none` would.